# Reading CSV files into Dask DataFrames using usecols

Tags: python, dataframe, dask, dask-dataframe

I am reading CSV file in dask but while reading, I want to "usecols" as we use in panads.

What I am currently using for DASK,

```
df = dd.read_csv('myfiles.csv')  #in dask
```

I want to use like this as we can do in pandas,

```
df = pd.read_csv('myfiles.csv',usecols=["date", "loc", "x"])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
df = dd.read_csv('myfiles.csv',names=["date", "loc", "x"])
```

Here is a definition from [pandas.read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv)

**names** *array-like, optional*

List of column names to use. If the file contains a header row, then you should explicitly pass `header=0` to override the column names. Duplicates in this list are not allowed.

You can use Extra keyword arguments to forward to `pandas.read_csv()`.
[dask.dataframe.read_csv](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/generated/dask.dataframe.read_csv.html) so even

```
df = dd.read_csv('myfiles.csv',usecols=["date", "loc", "x"])
```

will work for you.